# redis ERR unknown command 'UNLINK'

Tags: redis

I am facing issue while trying to use the UNLINK command with redis. Version that I am using is 5.0.8.

Any work around with this?

```
 root@test:/tmp/redis-stable# redis-cli --version 
 redis-cli 5.0.8
 root@test:/tmp/redis-stable# redis-cli
 127.0.0.1:6379> keys
 (error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'keys' command
 127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
 1) "51"
 2) "key2"
 3) "key1"
 127.0.0.1:6379>
 127.0.0.1:6379>
 127.0.0.1:6379>
 127.0.0.1:6379> UNLINK key1
 (error) ERR unknown command 'UNLINK'
 127.0.0.1:6379>
 127.0.0.1:6379>
 127.0.0.1:6379>
 127.0.0.1:6379> UNLINK key1 key2
 (error) ERR unknown command 'UNLINK'
 127.0.0.1:6379>
 127.0.0.1:6379>
 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Is this a known issue or any version specific version..

Regards,
Vicky

Comment: What version does `INFO server` return? The `--version` switch only tells you about the cli's version...

Comment: @ItamarHaber: Thanks for the information, and I can see the problem

I get the following: # Server
redis_version:3.0.6

I upgraded my local installation on untuntu 16.04.. is there some file specific I can cross check this?

Comment: Thanks @ItamarHaber, on doing a SHUTDOWN from redis-cli and again starting the redis-server, resolved the issue. I am marking this as a valid answer!

Comment: Great, happy I could point you in the right direction and happy hunting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @ItamarHaber,

I did had an upgraded version of 5.0.8 running but seems the old version was being picked up.

On doing a SHUTDOWN from redis-cli and again starting the redis-server, resolved the issue.

Comment: It was the upgrade beyond v4 that made the command available, rather than the restart... https://redis.io/commands/unlink

Comment: @MarkSetchell: You are right in saying this, but I already had a version 5.0.8 installed but it was not being picked up. On restart, the new version kicked in and helped resolve the issue for me. Thanks for the inputs!